# How to automatically save on change in Backbone using localstorage?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Code:

```
  class Session extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: ->
      @bind 'change', @save
      console.log 'init'
  class SessionList extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Session
    localStorage: new Store 'sessions'

  sessions = new SessionList
  a = new Session x: 'test'
  sessions.add a    
  console.log a.get 'x'
  a.set x: 'new'
  console.log a.get 'x'
```

When loaded in a page with Backbone.localstorage, the console gives:

```
init
test
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localStorage' of undefined
  backbone-localstorage.js:70
Backbone.sync
_.extend.save
  backbone-localstorage.js:70
Backbone.Events.trigger
  backbone.js:304
_.extend.change
  backbone.js:117
```

And when I comment out the @bind call, I get the expected:

```
init
test
new
```

I can also save manually successfully after `a` has been added to `sessions` with a call to `a.save()`.

I guess the problem is that the Session constructor triggers the `change` event, and `save()` doesn't know what to do before `a` has been added to `sessions`? So I could instead do something like this:

```
class Session extends Backbone.Model
  set: (fields, ops) ->
    super fields, ops
    if (this has been added to a Collection)
      @save()
```

Is this the best way to do it? If yes, how do I fill in the if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to just call save instead of set.  so replace this:

`a.set x: 'new'`

with

`a.save x: 'new'`

hope that works for you